# Difference between object retrieved by EntityManager Find() and Parameter passed to methods?

Tags: java, sql, database, entitymanager

I am working on a Restaurant assignment

In the RestaurantManager class, I am coding CRUD methods

Say I have the following method

```
public Restaurant updateRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
    //get emf from a singleton supplier
    EntityManagerFactory emf = EMFSupplier.getInstance().getEMF();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Restaurant restaurantToBeUpdated = (Restaurant)em.find(Restaurant.class, restaurant.getRestaurantId);


    // Here's my question
    Set<Chefs> chefsFirstSet = restaurantToBeUpdated.getAllChefs();
    Set<Chefs> chefsSecondSet = restaurant.getAllChefs();

    //Both retrieve a set of chefs, one use Restaurant from em.find(), 
    //the other use "restaurant" parameter passed to this method

    What's the difference between this two sets?

}
```

Comment: One is the actual set of chefs of the restaurant stored in the database, and the other is the set of chefs of the restaurant passed as argument, which could contain anything, since we have no idea where this restaurant comes from.

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear.